# simplexml_load_file not working in a loop

Tags: php, xml

I have a set of XML files (about 50) in an array. I was trying to use simple load XML function in a loop. I am getting an internal server error. Time out is not an issue. Also, I have have tried splitting these to 10 XML groups and is working.

Please help.

```
foreach ($feed_arr as $feed) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    echo $feed.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the XML files (even a cut down version would help).  It would also help if you widened the code to show how your populating `$feed_arr`

Comment: Do this : ` $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed); var_dump( $xml );` know your data before looping it.

Answer (score 0):

### [How to get XML Tag and DATA Recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110063/simplexml-load-file-not-working-in-a-loop/46110264#46110264)

Use this little function to loop through your xml data recursively and output tag and data for your application.

```
<?php
//Load your xml file
$xml = simplexml_load_file('settings.xml');

//Get the XML Tags and Data recusively;
getXMLData($xml);


// Function;
function getXMLData($xml){
    $i=0; $name = "";

    foreach ($xml as $k){
        $tag = $k->getName();
        $tag_value = $xml->$tag;
        if ($name == $tag){ 
            $i++;    
         } 
            $name = $tag;     
            echo $tag .' '.$tag_value[$i].'<br />';

           getXMLData($xml->$tag->children());
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check that no errors are generated when loading your XML file :

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors();
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
if ($xml == false) {
  echo "error";
  foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    echo "$error->message";
  }
}
 ?>
```